# Why Ractive.js reset() and update() methods duplicate template when there is a helper with array.prototype.sort() and data with an empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, template-engine, ractivejs

I have a problem with a large template and I think I finally could reproduce it in a small jsfiddle. 
I don't understand the following behaviour when Ractive.js reset() and update() methods duplicate the template when there is a helper with array.prototype.sort() and the data has an empty object like this:

```
[
   {id : 4, name: "Ringo", username: "Star43"},
   {id : 2, name: "Paul", username: "Pmac44"},
   {id : 1, name: "John", username: "Jony41"},
   {id : 3, name: "George", username: "Harris44"},
   {}
]
```

I don't know if this is a bug or a behaviour I just don't understand.

The helper is this:

```
       sort : function(arr){
           //return arr
           arr.sort(function(a, b){
               return a.id - b.id
           })
           return arr
       }
```

If I uncomment the first

```
//return arr
```

Then reset() and update() don't duplicate the template

This is the obligatory jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/rfuzxwv8/

And the Stackoverflow Code snippet:
You can just click in reset and update buttons.

```js
    var Section = Ractive.extend({
        el: 'container',
        template: '#table-template',
        data: {
            headers: [
                {id : 5, name: "Id"},
                {id : 7, name: "Name"},
                {id : 9, name: "Username"},
                {}
            ],
            rows : [
            {id : 4, name: "Ringo", username: "Star43"},
            {id : 2, name: "Paul", username: "Pmac44"},
            {id : 1, name: "John", username: "Jony41"},
            {id : 3, name: "George", username: "Harris44"},
            {}
                ],
               capitalize : function(string){
                   return string.toUpperCase()
               },
               sort : function(arr){
                   //return arr
                   arr.sort(function(a, b){
                       return a.id - b.id
                   })
                   console.log("arr.length: " + arr.length)
                   console.log(arr)
                   return arr
               }               
              }     
    });
    var rSection = new Section({        
    }) 
    
    document.querySelector("#btnreset").addEventListener("click", function(){ rSection.reset() }, false )
    
    document.querySelector("#btnupdate").addEventListener("click", function(){ rSection.update() }, false )
```

```css
table, td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js"></script>
<script type="x-template" id="table-template">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#sort(headers)}}
            <th> {{name}} </th>          
            {{/headers}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#sort(rows)}}
        <tr>
            <td> {{id}} </td>
            <td> {{capitalize(name)}} </td>
            <td> {{username}}</td>            
        </tr>
        {{/rows}}        
    </tbody>        
    <tbody>
    </tbody>    
</table>    
    
    <input type="button" value = "Ractive.reset()" id="btnreset"/>
    <input type="button" value = "Ractive.update()" id="btnupdate"/>
</script>

    <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the headers? The headers won't change. If you change `{{#sort(headers)}}` to just `{{#headers}}` I don't see this issue.

Comment: @Mathletics Interesting, thank you for the remark. In this case headers are already ordered but this JSfiddle is a huge simplification of a bigger template with different and disordered headers. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly a bug - there's been [a very similar one](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/748) before. It happens because `.sort()` modifies the original array while it's being rendered and Ractive renders it twice. You can work around this by creating a copy of the array before sorting it using `.slice()` method:

```
function (arr) {
    //return arr
    arr.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with this and your answer solves my problem with the helper. I opened an issue in the Github repo: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1359